# Is this a candidate for computational expressions?

Tags: c#, f#, monads

I have the following c# code, it does a check on permissions. I'm wondering if, when converted to f#, would computational expressions be a way to factor out the null checks.

```
bool ShouldGrantPermission(ISecurityService security, User user, Item item) {
  return user != null && item != null && user.Id == item.AuthorId
    && security.Does(user).Have(MyPermission).On(item);
}
```

I would like to note that the ISecurityService API currently returns false if any of the items are null. However it makes a database call, so the code here checks for null and then does the id check, because in most cases this will return false and avoid a database call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a computation builder that hides `null` checking, but it doesn't give you a very convenient syntax, so I probably wouldn't write it that way. It would be cool if there was some more lightweight syntax for this, because it would be quite useful. Also, the computation builder just propagates the `null`, so you would end with a result of type `Nullable<bool>`:

```
nullable { let! u = user
           let! i = item
           return u.Id == i.AuthorId && security.Does(user).Have(MyPermission).On(i) }
```

The idea is that the `let!` operation calls the rest of the computation only when the argument is not `null`. When it is `null`, it immediately returns `null` as the overall result.

I don't think there is much you could do to make the code nicer. Of course, if it was all written in F#, then none of the values could be `null` (because F# declared types do not permit the `null` value), but that's a different story.

Another approach in F# would be to declare an *active pattern* that matches only when a value is not `null`. This has the benefit that you won't have any variables that may have `null` value in the code, so there is no danger of using a wrong variable and getting `NullReferenceException`:

```
let shouldGrantPermission = function
  | NotNull(security:ISecurityService), NotNull(user), NotNull(item) ->
      security.Does(user).Have(MyPermission).On(item)
  | _ -> true
```

The declaration of the active pattern is:

```
let (|NotNull|_|) a = if a <> null then Some(a) else None
```

However, even this isn't really too much nicer than the direct equivalent of what you have. I guess dealing with `null` values is just pain :-). This [article by Ian Griffiths](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/04/13/member-lifting) has some related ideas, but again, none of them really solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I'm a little less worried about my understanding of monads now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would make one slight adjustment to Tomas's answer: use `Object.ReferenceEquals` to do the null check instead of `=`. It's faster and, more importantly, you don't have to mark types declared in F# with the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute. I generally define an `Interop` module for F# code that will be used from C#. This isolates null handling, and since it doesn't require the use of `[<AllowNullLiteral>]`, you can ignore null within F# and only deal with it at the point of interaction with C# (i.e., your public interface). Here's the module I use (copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462398/nullreferenceexception-in-f/5463951#5463951)):

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module Interop =

    let inline (===) a b = obj.ReferenceEquals(a, b)
    let inline (<=>) a b = not (a === b)
    let inline isNull value = value === null
    let inline nil<'T> = Unchecked.defaultof<'T>
    let inline safeUnbox value = if isNull value then nil else unbox value
    let (|Null|_|) value = if isNull value then Some() else None

type Foo() = class end

type Test() =
    member this.AcceptFoo(foo:Foo) = //passed from C#
        if isNull foo then nullArg "foo"
        else ...

    member this.AcceptFoo2(foo:Foo) = //passed from C#
        match foo with
        | Null -> nullArg "foo"
        | _ -> ...

    member this.AcceptBoxedFoo(boxedFoo:obj) =
        let foo : Foo = safeUnbox boxedFoo
        ...

    member this.ReturnFoo() : Foo = //returning to C#
        if (test) then new Foo()
        else nil
```

[Snippet](http://fssnip.net/4G) on fssnip.net.

Comment: Along these lines, having a couple reference equals and not equals operators around is handy: `let inline (=&) a b = obj.ReferenceEquals(a,b)` and `let inline (<>&) a b = a =& b |> not`

Comment: Ah, yes, I like to keep those handy myself, but I prefer the JavaScript-y `===` and `!==`.

Comment: Cool, I was considering using those also

Comment: The only problem with `!==` is that `!` doesn't mean "not" anywhere else in F#. Some might call it an abomination, but I almost think `<<>>` would be a more idiomatic companion to `===`.

Comment: @Joel: Yep, that's an abomination. :-) I settled on `===` and `<=>` until someone suggests something better.

Comment: @Joel: The fish operator? :-)

Comment: @Daniel - `<>=<` I fear it's only a matter of time until the "Doing Math with ASCII Art" blog post.

Comment: @Daniel, @Joel: I chose `=&` and `<>&` since `&` hearkens to the pass by reference operator `&`, and of course leading with `=` and `<>` is self-explanatory (and also ensures precedences and associativity are in line with the normal equals / not equals operators).

Comment: @Stephen - I'm not really wild about how your operators look, but I can't fault your reasoning.

Comment: It's a shame F# doesn't support unicode operators! We could use for example `=•=` and `<•>` (bullet represents `null`, which is quite appropriate, because it is great for shooting yourself into the foot :-)).

Comment: @Tomas: "It's a shame F# doesn't support unicode operators!". Amen! I'd love to be able to use ×, ±, ⊕, ⊗ and so on. Also ∂ in identifiers...

Comment: @Jon - Then you could also sell a special keyboard with your libraries :-).