# Handling Null Values in F#

Tags: c#, f#, interop, null

I need to interop with some C# code with F#. Null is a possible value that it is given so I need to check if the value was null. The docs suggest using pattern matching as such:

```
match value with
| null -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

The problem I'm having is the original code is structured in C# as:

```
if ( value != null ) {
    ...
}
```

How do I do the equivalent in F#? Is there a no-op for pattern matching? Is there a way to check for null with an if statement?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you don't want to do anything in the null case, then you can use the unit value `()`:

```
match value with
| null -> ()
| _ -> // your code here
```

Of course, you could also do the null check just like in C#, which is probably clearer in this case:

```
if value <> null then
    // your code here
```

Comment: This just seemed to be me misunderstanding the operators. Finally found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx

Answer (score 63):

For some reason (I haven't yet investigated why) `not (obj.ReferenceEquals(value, null))` performs much better than `value <> null`. I write a lot of F# code that is used from C#, so I keep an ["interop" module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462398/nullreferenceexception-in-f/5463951#5463951) around to ease dealing with `null`. Also, if you'd rather have your "normal" case first when pattern matching, you can use an active pattern:

```
let (|NotNull|_|) value = 
  if obj.ReferenceEquals(value, null) then None 
  else Some()

match value with
| NotNull ->
  //do something with value
| _ -> nullArg "value"
```

If you want a simple `if` statement, this works too:

```
let inline notNull value = not (obj.ReferenceEquals(value, null))

if notNull value then
  //do something with value
```

### UPDATE

Here are some benchmarks and additional information on the performance discrepancy:

```
let inline isNull value = (value = null)
let inline isNullFast value = obj.ReferenceEquals(value, null)
let items = List.init 10000000 (fun _ -> null:obj)
let test f = items |> Seq.forall f |> printfn "%b"

#time "on"
test isNull     //Real: 00:00:01.512, CPU: 00:00:01.513, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
test isNullFast //Real: 00:00:00.195, CPU: 00:00:00.202, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

A speed-up of 775% -- not too bad. After looking at the code in .NET Reflector: `ReferenceEquals` is a native/unmanaged function. The `=` operator calls [`HashCompare.GenericEqualityIntrinsic<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806482.aspx), ultimately ending up at the internal function [`GenericEqualityObj`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L1412-1441). In Reflector, this beauty decompiles to 122 lines of C#. Obviously, equality is a complicated issue. For `null`-checking a simple reference comparison is enough, so you can avoid the cost of subtler equality semantics.

### UPDATE 2

Pattern matching also avoids the overhead of the equality operator. The following function performs similarly to `ReferenceEquals`, but only works with types defined outside F# or decorated with `[<AllowNullLiteral>]`.

```
let inline isNullMatch value = match value with null -> true | _ -> false

test isNullMatch //Real: 00:00:00.205, CPU: 00:00:00.202, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

#### UPDATE 3

As noted in Maslow's comment, an [`isNull` operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/2d413fb940aa1677688454c50b8ec05cd3b6f78f/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3785-L3789) was added in F# 4.0. It's defined the same as `isNullMatch` above, and therefore performs optimally.

Comment: what changes does this answer need based on the new `isNull` in F# 4? `Operators.isNull : value:'T -> bool when 'T : null` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/04/29/rounding-out-visual-f-4-0-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx

Comment: @Maslow obj.ReferenceEquals takes `obj` parameters, so you don't have to first upcast it

Answer (score 17):

If you have a type that has been declared in C# or a .NET library in general (not in F#) then `null` is a proper value of that type and you can easily compare the value against `null` as posted by kvb. For example, assume that C# caller gives you an instance of `Random`:

```
let foo (arg:System.Random) =
  if arg <> null then 
    // do something
```

Things become more tricky if the C# caller gives you a type that was declared in F#. Types declared in F# do not have `null` as a value and F# compiler will not allow you to assign them `null` or to check them against `null`. The problem is that C# doesn't do this check and a C# caller could still give you `null`. For example:

```
type MyType(n:int) =
  member x.Number = n
```

In that case, you need either boxing or `Unchecked.defaultOf<_>`:

```
let foo (m:MyType) =
  if (box m) <> null then
    // do something

let foo (m:MyType) =
  if m <> Unchecked.defaultOf<_> then
    // do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course nulls are generally discouraged in F#, but...

Without going into examples etc there's an article with some examples @ MSDN [***here***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233197.aspx#Y400).  It reveals specifically how to detect a null -- and you can then parse it out of the input or handle as desired.

Comment: The problem is that real life often hands you nasty chains of C# classes, so you have to do ugly things like "if (vc <> null && vc.NavigationController <> null && vc.NavigationController.NavigationBar <> null)".  It's not really a single null by itself that's painful.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced a [similar dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240421/should-i-null-protect-my-f-code-from-c-sharp-calls). My issue was that I exposed an F#-developed API that could be consumed from C# code. C# has no issue passing `null` to a method that accepts interfaces or classes, but if the method and the types of its arguments are F# types, you are not allowed to properly do the null checks.

The reason is that F# types initially do not accept the `null` literal, while technically nothing in the CLR protects your API from being improperly invoked, especially from a more null-tolerant language such as C#. You would initially end up being unable to properly null-protect yourself unless you use the `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` attribute, which is quite an ugly approach.

So, I've come to [this solution in the related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44243641/795158), which allows me to keep my F# code clean and F#-friendly. In general I create a function that will accept any object and will convert it to an `Option`, then instead of `null` I will validate against `None`. This is similar to using the pre-defined in F# `Option.ofObj` function, but the latter does require the object passed to be explicitly nullable (thus annotated with the `AllowNullLiteral` uglyness).

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to do this

```
open System

Object.ReferenceEquals(value, null)
```