# Inconsistent behavior in pattern matching

Tags: f#

```
type Bar = A | B
type Foo = C of Bar | D of Bar
let case = Unchecked.defaultof<Foo>;;

match case with
| C A -> ""
| C B -> ""
| _ -> "Matches";;

match case with
| C A -> ""
| D B -> ""
| _ -> "Throws"
```

Quickly skimming over the F# Language Spec, nothing about null-test (which I can't do anyway) seemed related and both types seems to be reference type (AFAIK).

I would assume the behavior in the first case to be correct one.

Comment: Looking at the output in Reflector it seems like a bug. Incidentally, there are _many_ ways to do the null check in a match.

Comment: I'm thinking ``let (|Null|_|) o = if box o = null then Some () else None`` but would appreciate knowing of any other smarter ways.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6818329/162396 for some ways to handle this.

Comment: For more fun, see what happens when you run `match case with | C _ -> "C" | D _ -> "D"`.  Perhaps this will give you a hint why you see the behavior you do.

Comment: Clearly from John's research into the spec and your comments we have to conclude it is a bug.

Comment: @DavidGrenier: I don't think so. See my answer. It's "undefined," which isn't a bug.

Comment: @DavidGrenier: I disagree. Pattern matching abnormal values should give undefined behaviour. Otherwise you're going to bog down every compiled pattern match with unnecessary checks just so that it handles garbage data (that should *never* get there) that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern match against a DU with two cases compiles to an `if/else` with type tests. If you translate your examples, the behavior is apparent.

```
match case with
| C A -> ""
| C B -> ""
| _ -> "Matches"
```

translates to

```
if (case is C) 
  ...
else
  "Matches"
```

and

```
match case with
| C A -> ""
| D B -> ""
| _ -> "Throws"
```

translates to

```
if (case is D)
  ...
else //must be C
  //check tag  BANG! NRE
```

And kvb's example: `match case with | C _ -> "C" | D _ -> "D"`

```
if (case is D)
  //...
else //must be C
  "C"
```

I suppose you could view this as a reasonable optimization (vs. `if (case is D) {...} else if (case is C) {...} else { MatchFailureException }`) given that `null` behavior is undefined.

Add a third case to `Foo` and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 3):

I think all bets are off once you use `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` (thus the "Unchecked" ;-)).  Null isn't considered a valid value for type `Foo` from an F# perspective (although it is from the .NET perspective), so I don't think that the pattern matching semantics are defined.

What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't think the behavior of Unchecked.defaultof<_> here is at question, as I'm using the same value in both pattern match. I was just playing around - "The semantics for this are undefined" may well be the correct answer.

Comment: @DavidGrenier: "I'm using the same value in both pattern match". I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

So reading the spec, the first hint is here

> b)    Types with null as an abnormal value. These are types that do
>   not admit the null literal, but do have null as an abnormal value.
>
> Types in this category are:
>
> o    All F# list, record, tuple, function, class and interface types.
>
> o    All F# union types apart from those with null as a normal value
>   (as discussed in the next paragraph).
>
> For these types, the use of the null literal is not directly
>   permitted. However it is, strictly speaking, possible to generate a
>   null value for these types using certain functions such as
>   Unchecked.defaultof. For these types, null is considered an
>   abnormal value. The behavior of operations with respect to null values
>   is defined in §6.9.

This does seem to suggest that on passing in a null value for your union could be some sort of undefined behaviour as the value is "abnormal", Section 6.9 isn't particularly helpful

Looking at the definition for `_`, it seems like you are right that this is a bug - it states

> 7.1.7        Wildcard Patterns
>
> The pattern _ is a wildcard pattern and matches any input. For
>   example:
>
> let categorize x =
>
> ```
> match x with
>
> | 1 -> 0
>
> | 0 -> 1
>
> | _ -> 0
> ```

I think the most relevnat hints though are later on where the compiled methods for DU's are listed

> 8.5.3        Compiled Form of Union Types for Use from Other CLI Languages
>
> A compiled union type U will have:
>
> ·         One CLI static getter property U.C for each nullary union
>   case C. This will get a singleton object representing that case.
>
> ·         One CLI nested type U.C for each non-nullary union case C.
>   This type will have instance properties Item1, Item2.... for each
>   field of the union case, or a single instance property Item if there
>   is only one field. A compiled union type with only one case does not
>   have a nested type. Instead, the union type itself plays the role of
>   the case type.
>
> ·         One CLI static method U.NewC for each non-nullary union case
>   C. This will construct an object for that case.
>
> ·         One CLI instance property u.IsC for each case C that returns
>   true or false for the case.
>
> ·         One CLI instance property u.Tag for each case C that fetches
>   or computes an integer tag corresponding to the case.

From this, you can see that all of the methods for checking are instance methods, which would require non-nullness.  Sine `null` is "abnormal", the generated code doesn't bother checking, so it throws.

I think you could argue that this is infact a bug, based on the definition of `_`.  However, fixing it would require inserting null checks before every DU pattern matching check, which would slow the code down significantly, so I doubt whether this will be fixed

Comment: Good analysis, but I think the wildcard is a bit of a red herring in the second case; if you delete that line you still get a `NullReferenceException` rather than a `MatchFailureException`.  The exception is being thrown when checking the other cases.

Comment: To elaborate, proper values of type `Foo` are either instances of `C` or instances of `D`.  In the first case, the compiler determines that `case` is not a `C`, and it is done.  In the second case, it determines that `case` is not a `C`, so it must be a `D` (it thinks).  Then it accesses the generated `Item` property to check whether it is an `D A` or a `D B`, but because `case` is null this generates a null reference exception.

Comment: @kvb: In each of his examples, and yours, two cases are being checked and this is compiled to an `if/else`. Granted `null` behavior is undefined, but this seems odd (I would have expected `if/else if/else MatchFailureException`). I assume this is due to the DU only having two cases.

Answer (score 2):

The description of the method Unchecked.defaultof ends with the sentence "This function is unsafe in the sense that some F# values don't have proper null values", which is exactly the case here.

Try this:

```
let isNull = (case = null) ;;

  let isNull = (case = null) ;;
  ---------------------^^^^

stdin(3,22): error FS0043: The type 'Foo' does not have 'null' as a proper value
>
```

DUs are intended to be immutable and don't have proper null values.

Comment: I'm really not advocating one way or another here, I'm just saying the behavior of both pattern match above should be identical.

Comment: Should be identical with "legal values". Unexpected values can produce unexpected results, not only with pattern match, I have more cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to confirm this at the moment, but wouldn't the AddNullLiteral attribute to the types allow the match to succeed?

Comment: `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` is not allowed on DUs.

Comment: Yep, found that out around the time you posted this. :) Thanks!