# F# using match to validate parameters

Tags: validation, parameters, f#, match

I'm learning F#.  I want to know best practices for validating input parameters. In my naivety  I had thought I could do something like this:

```
let foo = match bar with
| <test for valid> -> bar
| _ -> "invalid"
```

of course that doesn't work due to mismatching types.  So I'd like to see the patterns experienced F# programmers use for this sort of thing.  match? If/then/else?

Something else?

Comment: What is `bar`? Pattern matching is typically preferred over if/then/else

Comment: Check this out: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/

Comment: Definitely `match` - it offers more flexibility than `if/then/else`, but also more safeguards against errors in writing the checks itself. I wrote a couple of examples in a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570314/error-using-bool-parse-on-null-empty-values/41570469#41570469): type tests, matching against `out` parameters

Comment: Thanks Anton, actually the example just below yours is closer to what I was thinking:

Comment: Thanks Anton, actually the example just below yours is closer to what I was thinking: `let (|Bool|) str =
   match System.Boolean.TryParse(str) with
   | (true,bool) -> Some(bool)
   | _ -> None   

let (|String|) (o:obj) = 
    match o with
    | :? string as s -> Some(s)
    | _ -> None ` though that leaves me with handling the None's separately to issue error messages.  How would you tweak your solution when the desired result is an integer but the error path is a string?

Answer (score 6):

You are having problems because you are trying to bind a value to something that could be two possible types depending upon program flow - that is incompatible with static typing.

If I have some value `foo`, it cannot be, for example, a `string` OR an `int` depending upon program flow; it must resolve to exactly one type at compile time.

You can, however, use a [discriminated union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions) that can represent several different options within a single type.

Here is a summary of the approaches for doing just that.

---

**Result Type / Either**

F# 4.1, which is currently available via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core), introduces the `Result` type.  You may find this type referred to as `Either` in other languages.

It is defined like this:

```
[<Struct>] 
type Result<'T,'TError> =  
    /// Represents an OK or a Successful result. The code succeeded with a value of 'T. 
    | Ok of ResultValue:'T  
    /// Represents an Error or a Failure. The code failed with a value of 'TError representing what went wrong. 
    | Error of ErrorValue:'TError
```

If you are pre-F# 4.1 (which is very likely).  You can define this type yourself, although you must remove the `[<Struct>]` attribute.

You can then make a `tryParseFloat` function:

```
let tryParseFloat str =
   match System.Double.TryParse str with
   |  true, f -> Ok f
   | _ -> Error <| sprintf "Supplied string (%s) is not a valid float" str
```

You can determine success or failure:

```
match tryParseFloat "0.0001" with
|Ok v -> // handle success
|Error err -> // handle error
```

In my opinion, this is the preferred option, especially in F# 4.1+ where the type is built in.  This is because it allows you to include information relating to how and why some activity failed.

---

**Option Type / Maybe**

The `option` type contains either `Some 'T` or simply `None`.  The option type is used to indicate the presence or absence of a value, `None` fills a role similar to `null` in other languages, albeit far more safely.

You may find this type referred to as `Maybe` in other languages.

```
let tryParseFloat str =
   match System.Double.TryParse str with
   |  true, f -> Some f
   | _ -> None
```

You can determine success or failure:

```
match tryParseFloat "0.0001" with
|Some value -> // handle success
|None -> // handle error
```

---

**Composition**

In both cases, you can readily compose options or results using the associated `map` and `bind` functions in the `Option` and `Result` modules respectively:

Map:

```
val map: mapping:('T -> 'U) -> option:'T option -> 'U option   
val map : mapping:('T -> 'U) -> result:Result<'T, 'TError> -> Result<'U, 'TError>
```

The `map` function lets you take an ordinary function from `'a -> 'b` and makes it operate on results or options.

Use case: combine a result with a function that will always succeed and return a new result.

> ```
> tryParseFloat "0.001" |> Result.map (fun x -> x + 1.0);;
> val it : Result<float,string> = Ok 1.001
> ```

Bind:

```
val bind: binder:('T -> 'U option) -> option:'T option -> 'U option
val bind: binder:('T -> Result<'U, 'TError>) -> result:Result<'T, 'TError> -> Result<'U, 'TError>
```

The `bind` function lets you combine results or options with a function that takes an input and generates a result or option

Use case: combine a result with another function that may succeed or fail and return a new result.

Example:

```
let trySqrt x =
   if x < 0.0 then Error "sqrt of negative number is imaginary"
   else Ok (sqrt x)
```

> ```
> tryParseFloat "0.001" |> Result.bind (fun x -> trySqrt x);;
> val it : Result<float,string> = Ok 0.0316227766
>
> tryParseFloat "-10.0" |> Result.bind (fun x -> trySqrt x);;
> val it : Result<float,string> = Error "sqrt of negative number is imaginary"
>
> tryParseFloat "Picard's Flute" |> Result.bind (fun x -> trySqrt x);;
> val it : Result<float,string> =
>   Error "Supplied string (Picard's Flute) is not a valid float"
> ```

---

Notice that in both cases, we return a single result or option despite chaining multiple actions - that means that by following these patterns you need only check the result once, after all of your validation is complete.

This avoids a potential readability nightmare of nested `if` statements or `match` statements.

A good place to read more about this is the [Railway Oriented Programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) article that was mentioned to you previously.

**Exceptions**

Finally, you have the option of throwing exceptions as a way of preventing some value from validating.  This is definitely not preferred if you expect it to occur but if the event is truly exceptional, this could be the best alternative.

Comment: Alas I cannot install Fsharp 4.1:PM> Install-Package FSharp.Core
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.ValueTuple (≥ 4.3.0)'.
Install-Package : The 'System.ValueTuple 4.3.0' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60318.667'.At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package FSharp.Core
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], NuGetVersionNotSatisfiedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: But I will try your solution.  One question about it.  I get an error on ResultValue: Error 1 The type 'ResultValue' is not defined .  How should it be defined?

Comment: yes,  though how do I get the actual float value from `match tryParseFloat "0.0001" with
|Ok v -> // handle success
|Error err -> // handle error`?

Comment: @user1443098 You get the result by pattern matching, in this case `v` is the float value you're looking for.  Remember though that the return type of each of the cases must be the same, a valid way of handling the result would be, as a simple example, `match tryParseFloat "0.0001" with |Ok v -> printfn "%f" v |Error err -> printfn "%s" err`.

Answer (score 4):

The basic way of representing invalid states in F# is to use the `option` type, which has two possible values. `None` represents invalid state and `Some(<v>)` represents a valid value `<v>`.

So in your case, you could write something like:

```
let foo = 
  match bar with
  | <test for valid> -> Some(bar)
  | _ -> None
```

The `match` construct works well if `<test for valid>` is actual pattern (e.g. empty list or a specific invalid number or a `null` value), but if it is just a boolean expression, then it is probably better to write the condition using `if`:

```
let foo = 
  if <test for valid> bar then Some(bar)
  else None
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along this lines

```
type Bar =
    | Bar of string
    | Foo of int

let (|IsValidStr|_|) x = if x = Bar "bar" then Some x else None
let (|IsValidInt|_|) x = if x = Foo 0 then Some x else None

let foo (bar:Bar) = 
    match bar with
    | IsValidStr x -> Some x
    | IsValidInt x -> Some x
    | _ -> None
```

That is you could use active patterns to check for the actual business rules and return an Option instance

Comment: You're not using the `Bar` type you defined. Did you mean to return it from the match?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what the OP wrote in the comments:

You would define a type as in the post that Fyodor [linked](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/), that captures your two possible outcomes:

```
type Result<'TSuccess,'TFailure> = 
    | Success of 'TSuccess
    | Failure of 'TFailure
```

Your validation code becomes:

```
let checkBool str =
   match bool.TryParse str with
   |  true, b -> Success b
   | _ -> Failure ("I can't parse this: " + str)
```

When using it, again use match:

```
let myInput = "NotABool"
match checkBool myInput with
| Success b -> printfn "I'm happy: %O" b
| Failure f -> printfn "Did not like because: %s" f
```

If you only would like to continue with valid bools, your code can only fail on invalid arguments, so you would do:

```
let myValidBool = 
    match checkBool myInput with
    | Success b -> b
    | Failure f -> failwithf "I did not like the args because: %s" f
```

Comment: This is all great stuff!  Thanks so much for the ideas

Comment: so in the last example, if myInput *is* a bool, how do I access it?  Is it now wrapped in a Result type?

Comment: By using the `Success` pattern, as shown in the last fragment: the `b` is bound to the wrapped bool.

Comment: Ah yes, so say I am processing cli args, argv e.g. and I want to check the first arg for a valid bool string (true/false), convert it to an actual bool and assign it to a new name to be used later.  Can I do that in one go using match?  e.g. to modify your example so I can say: let myBool = <something that does the check and conversion then yields a bool>

Comment: Updated the answer