# F# Validate input parameters

Tags: validation, f#, match

Working on a toy example to validate input parameters and issue an error message if invalid.  So far I have:

```
let usage = 
    printfn "Usage:  %s " (Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)
    exit -1


let test what date id flag = 
    let date =
        match DateTime.TryParse date with
        | (true, d) -> Some d
        | _ -> usage

    let id =
        match Int32.TryParse id with
        | (true, int) -> Some int
        | _ -> usage // error here

    0

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    match argv with
    | [| what;  date; id; flag |] -> test
    | _ -> usage
```

but this gives errors:

> Error 1   Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       int option     but given a
>       DateTime option     The type 'int' does not match the type 'DateTime'

Where is it getting the DateTime type from?  The first match?  but then, why? What is the right way to write a catch-all error handler without getting type errors?

Comment: You are trying to bind a value to something that could be two different types, you need to look at the way the answers are structured in your other question.  If you are returning `Option`, the only valid thing you can return from your failure branch in your pattern match is the value `None`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# using match to validate parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557725/f-using-match-to-validate-parameters)

Comment: I've updated my answer to your other question to hopefully better explain.  I suggest this be closed because it really is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

"Problem number 1 :

```
let usage =
```

This is not a function. You most probably want

```
let usage () =
```

You must call that function like this.

```
usage ()
```

Problem number 2 :

The cause of the error is that based on type inference, usage returns a DateTime option.

The first of these two lines is where the compiler determines that the match expression will return DateTime option. The second line is where the compiler infers that "usage" must also be DateTime option, since the match expression returns DateTime option.

```
| (true, d) -> Some d
| _ -> usage
```

How can usage become DateTime option? Because you use "exit -1", and the signature of exit is int->'T, so that "usage" will actually be forced by the compiler to return a specific type based on the type inference. It is forced to the type "DateTime option", which is not what you want. To prevent this, you can declare your intended result type of usage, or you can explicitly return the value you intended. I'll do both here, to illustrate it all.

```
let usage () : unit = 
    printfn "Usage:  %s " (Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)
    exit -1
    ()
```

Now "usage" has been locked down to a signature of unit->unit, which simplifies further work for us.

Problem number 3 :

F# is a functional language, and not an imperative language. The "usage" function is rather problematic. I suggest you replace it with use of "failwith" instead, and catch the error with a "try" in "main", as shown below. An alternative is that "using" return 'T, same as "failwith" does, if you really do want to be able to terminate the program anywhere. Not recommended, since that kind of use can make things hard for you to understand at this stage. Your program will then exit with no sign of what possibly went wrong. Better to handle expected and unexpected exceptions as shown below, and terminate cleanly from the main function.

```
let test what date id flag = 
    let date =
        match DateTime.TryParse date with
        | (true, d) -> Some d
        | _ -> failwith "Error 1 here."
    let id =
        match Int32.TryParse id with
        | (true, int) -> Some int
        | _ -> failwith "Error 2 here."
    ()

let main argv =
    try
        match argv with
        | [| what;  date; id; flag |] -> test what date id flag
        | _ -> failwith "Error 3 here."
        0
    with ex ->
        printfn "Error: %s" ex.Message
        printfn "Usage: %s" (Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)
        -1
```

Comment: So, I've implemented this approach and it works so far.  Next thing I need to know is how to subsequently use the variables "date" and "id" in the main function.  I tried adding: printfn "%d %i" date id ... just after the match statement but that fails with "the value or constructor 'date' is not found"

Comment: The date and id is only accessible (in scope we say) after the arrow, where it says "test what date id flag". That's where you need to put your print statement, or whatever else should happen when this pattern occurs. The "after the match statement" place, is a place where you can end up even if not matching and having date and id, so it doesn't make sense that they should be available (in scope) there.

Comment: F# is an extremely safe language, which to a very high degree forces you to do things right, and helps you do it simple. You seem to have a strong tendency towards imperative style thinking. That makes it much harder for you. Functional programming is based on lambda calculus - or in plain speech, it really truly is algebra - or expressions if you will - the whole darned thing. Start seeing it like that, and it will be of immense help to you.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see.  So I I want to act on the values assigned in the match statement, I need to do it there, not later.  Yes, I certainly have a strong bias towards imperative style thinking!  After all, I've been doing it all my life.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to modularize things and obey the SRP.  e.g. parse the input variables, if bad, issue an error and terminate.  if good, use the variables in the next part

Comment: I recommend the site [F# for fun and profit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com) where you will find the ["Thinking functionally" series](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/thinking-functionally.html) amongst many others.